# Установка qt 5.5.1 msvc 2012 на виндовс 64

Tags: qt, visual-studio, qt5, qmake

Установил Майкрософт вижуал студию 2012. Она прекрасно установилась.

После установил Qt5.5.1 с компилятором msvc 2012. Установилась нормально без ошибок, qmake есть, но почему то не собирает пустой проект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что творится в  панеле "Проекты"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @Alexander Chernin как только открыл   создание проекта , то понял что там полная чепуха :3  Зашёл в в кладку "параметры" -> "настройка и запуск " -> "основное" и  поправил там расположение файлов (просто переписал с йе в которой у меня всё работает).

И теперь все работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]